# Как запустить функцию из функции в python?

Tags: python, функции

В задании даны две переменные с исходными данными следующей структуры:

```
documents = [
{‘type’: ‘passport’, ‘number’: ‘2207 876234’, ‘name’: ‘Василий Гупкин’},
{‘type’: ‘invoice’, ‘number’: ‘11-2’, ‘name’: ‘Геннадий Покемонов’},
{‘type’: ‘insurance’, ‘number’: ‘10006’, ‘name’: ‘Аристарх Павлов’}
]

directories = {
‘1’: [‘2207 876234’, ‘11-2’],
‘2’: [‘10006’],
‘3’: []
}
```

*Общие требования к программе:
код должен быть грамотно декомпозирован (каждая функция отвечает за свою конкретную задачу, дублирующийся функционал переиспользуется, а его код не повторяется);
в коде отсутствуют глобальные переменные (за исключением documents и directories);
пользовательский ввод обрабатывается в цикле while до тех пор, пока пользователь явно не завершит программу (вводом команды “q”).*

Задача: написать ряд функций, каждая из которых выполняют свою задачу, например:

```
def doc_all():
    document_number = input("Введите номер документа: ")
    for x in documents:
        if x['number'] == document_number:
            return(f"Владелец документа:  {x['name']}")
    print('Документ не найден в базе')

doc_all()
```

или:

```
def shelf_all():
    document_number = input("Введите номер документа: ")
    for b in directories:
        if document_number in directories[b]:
            return('Документ хранится на полке: ' + b)
    return('Документ не найден в базе')

shelf_all()
```

Далее нужно написать функцию, вызывающую все эти функции по определенной команде. Вот то, что сделал (но это не работает):

```
def main ():
    command_dict = {
        'p': doc_all,
        's': shelf_all,
        'l': list_all,
        'ads': add_shelf,
        'ds': del_shelf
    }
    
    while True:
        command_request = input("Введите команду: ")
        if command_request in command_dict:
            res = command_dict[command_request](documents,directories)
            
            print(res)
        elif command_request == "q":
            print('Работа окончена.')
            break
            
main()
```

TypeError: doc_all() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Я понимаю, что что-то с аргументами, которые прописываю в функцию, но что именно не так, не понимаю. Спасибо

Comment: вы передаете в функцию два параметра, но в сигнатуре вашей функции этих параметров нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы вот тут:

```
res = command_dict[command_request](documents,directories)
```

по сути вызываете функцию, например doc_all. В другом месте у вас описана эта функция, в данном случае -

```
def doc_all():
```

Из определения функции ясно, что у нее нет параметров. А вы ей подсовываете два. Зачем вы их передаете этой или какой другой функции -  сие мне не ведомо. Разбирайтесь сами. Но что-бы "проскочить" указанную вам ошибку напишите, например, вот так:

```
res = command_dict[command_request]()
```

Другое дело, что в самой функции у вас вдруг возникает documents вот тут:

```
for x in documents:
```

При этом, что такое documents, нигде не описано. В общем, какой-то набор ошибки на ошибке. Разбирайтесь.

Comment: спасибо теперь работает. в for x in documents: передаю значения из переменной documents. И у меня эта функция вроде нормально работает и отдельно и при вызове из функции main. все функции теперь нормально работают, кроме: def add_shelf():
    number = input("Введите номер полки: ")
    x = directories.keys()
    if number in x:
        print('Такая полка уже существует. Текущий перечень полок: ' + ', ' .join (x))
    else: 
        directories[number] = []
        return ('Полка добавлена. Текущий перечень полок: ' + ', ' .join (x))
        
add_shelf()

Comment: При вызове ее из main результат следующий: Такая полка уже существует. Текущий перечень полок: 1, 2, 3, 4
None

Comment: Вопрос по def add_shelf() снят. изменил print на return, работает без лишнего вывода none